# Retrieve most recent SNAPSHOT from different resolvers with sbt

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, sbt

I am writing an application using play 2.2.1 with sbt 0.13.0.
In this application I have a dependency to another project which is a snapshot and to which I also make some modifications. If I build that project it is written to my local Maven repository. But normally that project should be retrieved from a private online Maven repository.

How can I configure sbt to always retrieve the newest version of the snapshot, regardless if it has to be retrieved from my local Maven repository or the online Maven repository.

Till now I added this to my build.sbt:

```
resolvers += "Online Repo" at "https://online-repo.com/somePath"
resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file:///"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/" 
libraryDependencies += "com.some.project" % "a-project" % "2.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

The problem with this is that the project is retrieved from the first resolver. In this case "Online Repo". Although the Snapshot in "Local Maven Repository" could be newer.

Comment: Do you want SBT to check **all** resolvers for latest available version? I doubt it's possible. I doubt it's even possible in *any* build tool. As a workaround, you could publish the dependency to m2 repo as well as Ivy's local repo.

Comment: No, not all resolvers need to be checked. It is enough if the two mentioned resolvers will be checked. Thank you for your comment, because I probably ran into an error in reasoning due to two build tools involved.

Comment: Does this mean you will *eventually* remove the question?

Comment: I think it would still be useful. Especially as sbt makes it very easy to use Maven and therefor I think I am not the only one, who has this problem.

Comment: Now when I think about it, I think SBT and other build tools check all the defined repositories for the latest version of a dependency and when they consult all of them, SBT and others decide what version to pull down. How could I have thought it should be otherwise?!

Answer (score 1):

> How can I configure sbt to always retrieve the newest version of the
>   snapshot, regardless if it has to be retrieved from my local Maven
>   repository or the online Maven repository.

According to [Dependency Management Flow](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Dependency-Management-Flow.html):

> update resolves dependencies according to the settings in a build
>   file, such as libraryDependencies and resolvers.

and

> Directly running the update task (as opposed to a task that depends on
>   it) will force resolution to run, whether or not configuration
>   changed. This should be done in order to refresh remote SNAPSHOT
>   dependencies.

which means that SBT does this by design.